# Remove/Drop Rows if both different column values have same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lines-of-code

df

```
snip,Fbuffmeal_beta,Mbuffmeal_beta
rs11571877,-4.4,-5.9
kgp17983401,63.4,-2.1
kgp17731494,1.2,1.0
kgp2277054,-8.66333,-29.222
```

How to remove/drop rows only if both Fbuffmeal_beta & Mbuffmeal_beta column values are less than 0.1?

Desired Output:

```
snip,Fbuffmeal_beta,Mbuffmeal_beta
kgp17983401,63.4,-2.1
kgp17731494,1.2,1.0
```

I have tried this code:

```
df.loc[(df['Fbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1) & (df['Mbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1)]
```

but returning rows of which I want to remove

```
snip,Fbuffmeal_beta,Mbuffmeal_beta
rs11571877,-4.4,-5.9
kgp2277054,-8.66333,-29.222
```

can anyone help me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is it strictly **less than** or **less than or equal** to 0.1? Just change your loc equalities from `...<0.1 &...` to either  `...>0.1 |...` or `...>=0.1 |...`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert mask to `>=` with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['Fbuffmeal_beta'] >= 0.1) | (df['Mbuffmeal_beta'] >= 0.1)]
print (df1)
          snip  Fbuffmeal_beta  Mbuffmeal_beta
1  kgp17983401            63.4            -2.1
2  kgp17731494             1.2             1.0
```

Your solution is possible use with invert mask by `~`:

```
df.loc[~((df['Fbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1) & (df['Mbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1))]
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the negation on the outside of the next layer of parentheses?

Comment: @cornifer - oops, it was typo.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[~((df['Fbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1) & (df['Mbuffmeal_beta'] < 0.1))]
```